# Compile-time extensions in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

One of the possibilities demoed when the C# dev team was talking about porting the C# compiler to C# was the option to extend the compiler phase with custom plugins, written in C#.

Was that option included in the Visual Studio 2015 release, and if so, where can I find the MSDN page for it?

Comment: You're looking for https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/Dn879356

Comment: There are some [samples and walkthroughs](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Samples%20and%20Walkthroughs) included in the Roslyn Git repo

Comment: The CodePlex site @MatthewStrawbridge linked to is our old site; we've since moved on to GitHub. Current page is https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Samples-and-Walkthroughs.